# Proguard Rules for local classes

Tags: android, obfuscation, android-proguard

I want to know what does mean by

```
-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
public private *;
}

-keep class * {
public private protected *;
}
```

And what if there are some model classes there in my code have some primitive types and getter setters. I don't want to obfuscate there names specially "keys" what rule I should use for them?

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developers/practical-proguard-rules-examples-5640a3907dc9 check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [**`ProGuard`**](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/proguard/docs/index.html#manual/introduction.html) also optimizes the bytecode, removes unused code
>   instructions, and obfuscates the remaining classes, fields, and
>   methods with short names.

```
-keep public class packageName.ParticularClassName.** { *; }
```

> [**`@Keep`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/Keep) annotation to the code you want to keep. Adding **`@Keep`** on a class
>   keeps the entire class as-is. Adding it on a method or field will keep
>   the method/field (and it's name) as well as the class name intact.

Read [**`Customize which code to keep`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-code).